# jQuery blockUI set dynamic background imege

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here is on that sample http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos showed how to use Growl (the easy way)

so i need to put custom style like that:

```
div.growlUI { background: url(check48.png) no-repeat 10px 10px }
div.growlUI h1, div.growlUI h2 {
    color: white; padding: 5px 5px 5px 75px; text-align: left
}
```

so if action was successful that will work perfectly, but what about if action was unsuccessful, how i may set another background image(`background: url(error48.png) no-repeat 10px 10px`) in that case

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    $.blockUI({ css: {
        background: 'url(error48.png) no-repeat 10px 10px',
    } });
```

Comment: i did that first line on error: function(), no way also was trying that  `$.blockUI({ growlCSS: { background: .... });` same thing, `check48.png` still staying there

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any another ways to do that using explicit style definition

So using jQuery I did it like that:

```
 error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
                $.growlUI(null, 'Error uploading file, try again later');

                $('div.growlUI').css("background", "url(attention48.png) no-repeat 10px 10px");
            }
```